# How many times is a property applied in SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql

If I have a SPARQL query say,

```
PREFIX foaf <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
  ?x foaf:name ?name.
  ?x foaf:knows ?y.
}
```

to select the name of some x, who knows some y. How could I select only the names of those people who know exactly 3 other people (or any other number)?

Also, as a side question - is there a better title for this question? One which uses better terminology to clarify the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the title might be a bit confusing. But If you did not know of the existence of aggregates then I think that is not that bad. In the end the import thing is the content of the question that is good in this case.

Comment: @msalvadores Thanks. I didn't know this term applied to SPARQL as well as SQL, no..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that with [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) and it new features: GROUP BY, HAVING and SUBQUERIES. Something like this would do the job:

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    ?x foaf:name ?name .
    {
       SELECT ?x (count(?y) as ?count_y) WHERE {
              ?x foaf:knows ?y.
       } GROUP BY ?x 
         HAVING count(?y) > 3
    }
}
```

Unfortunately not all SPARQL engines support all these features together. That I know [Jena/ARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/) and [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/presentations/SPARQL_Tutorials/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_2/SPARQL_Tutorials_Part_2.html#%281%29) support them.

If you are working with an SPARQL engine that doesn't support these features then I recommend to run the query:

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
  ?x foaf:name ?name.
  ?x foaf:knows ?y.
}
```

... and programatically compute the rest of the logic that you need in the query with few lines of client-side code.

Comment: So having SPARQL 1.1. Does that depend on the endpoint, or my Jena/ARQ library, or both?

Comment: Also, presumably that would be ==, not >

Comment: @Aidan Yes for exactly 3 friends change it to `=` (note single equals for equality in SPARQL).  SPARQL 1.1 support depends on the endpoint, whether you need a library that supports it depends on whether the library will parse/validate the query prior to sending it to an endpoint.  If the library doesn't do this then just the endpoint need support SPARQL 1.1 as the results format used to encode the results by the endpoint looks exactly the same and can be interpreted by a library unaware of SPARQL 1.1